# ARP Cache location on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, arp

I'm just a beginner in studying the command prompt in windows 10.

Out of curiosity I wanted to ask:

1. Where does the command prompt reads or writes the ARP Cache data from in windows 10? Meaning, the data in the ARP Cache (ARP Table) where is it actually located/stored for windows 10?
2. If it is stored on the hard-drive, then in what file is it stored? If I deleted that file or it becomes corrupted, then what would happen if I executed the `arp -a` command in cmd?

Comment: It's stored in RAM.

Comment: Your source please?

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Where is the ARP Cache stored

It is stored in memory:

> The address resolution protocol (ARP) cache is a table in computer memory that maps a limited number of IP addresses to their physical adapter addresses. A computer's ARP cache contains its own entry, entries for machines that have made ARP broadcasts to it, and entries for machines to which it has made broadcasts.

Source [Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) Cache Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/99150/address-resolution-protocol-arp-cache-functions)

---

#### If the ARP Cache is deleted/corrupted, what would happen if I executed `arp -a`?

Nothing bad - it will rebuild the table.

Here I used `netsh` to delete the ARP Cache and then run `arp -a`.

As you can see there are no errors.

```
> netsh interface ip delete arpcache
Ok.


> arp -a

Interface: 192.168.42.78 --- 0x13
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.42.129        16-d1-b8-97-a9-29     dynamic
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [arp](https://ss64.com/nt/arp.html) - Address Resolution Protocol
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)